# Get error when trying to insert data into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using below code to do checking before data get inserted into MySQL. However, I get error as below

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM movie_title WHERE title = 'ABC')' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Here my code

```
public void checkAndAdd(String movieTitle) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DatabaseConnection db=new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connect=db.getConnection();
        String sql="INSERT INTO movie_title(title) VALUES (?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,movieTitle);
        ps.setString(2,movieTitle);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        connect.close();
        ps.close(); 

    }
```

**Edited**

```
String sql=" IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?) INSERT INTO movie_title (title) VALUES (?) ";
```

Comment: How to find your problem: take the SQL that you are executing in Java, copy it into mysql and run it. When mysql gives you an error, debug your SQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put a WHERE clause in your SQL when you're using the VALUES keyword.  Try something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)
    INSERT INTO movie_title (title)
    VALUES (?)
```

I work with SQL Server mostly, so I'm not sure if that's completely valid for MySQL, but it will be something similar.

Okay, for MySQL it has to be a little different:

```
INSERT INTO movie_title (title)
SELECT mt.title
FROM
    (SELECT ? title) mt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)
```

Comment: you mean  `String sql="IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)
    INSERT INTO movie_title (title)
    VALUES (?)";` ?

Comment: Yes, I just edited the query itself, but you can put it in a string like that.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM movie_title WHERE title = '1') INSERT INTO movie_tit' at line 1`

Comment: the movieTitle parameter holds 1. What should I change in this line `(SELECT 1 FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)`

Comment: Like mmcrae said above, try it directly in MySQL and debug from there.  The `SELECT 1` should be fine, I'm just not completely sure how to use the `?` for parameters.  Replace the `?` with actual values and test it that way first.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. This is the query I using `String sql="INSERT INTO movie_title (title) SELECT mt.title FROM (SELECT ? title) mt WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM movie_title WHERE title = ?)";`